# What are some examples of laser-based additive manufacturing techniques?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, lasers, photonics

I'm trying to research additive (or 'bottom-up') fabrication techniques that rely on lasers or other advanced photonic systems. So far, the most prevalent technique I've come across is two-photon polymerisation, but I'm struggling to find any others. Any further examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: selective laser melting, selective laser sintering and laser deposition welding with powder and/or wire come to mind

Comment: @OpticalResonator, please put your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an incomplete list of laser-based additive manufacturing, based on my comment. I might expand on it later:

- **Selective laser melting/sintering (SLM/SLS):** a laser beam melts/sinters a layer of powder at the desired spots, after solidification, a new layer is added and the process starts over.
- **Stereolitography:** basically the same as SLM, but instead of powder, you use a resin that solidifies when exposed to light. One of the oldest additive manufacturing processes.
- **Laser deposition welding:** a laser melts a spot on a base plate, additional material is fed into this melt pool in form of powder or wire (processes with both at once also exist, need to search a bit for a citation). From there on you build up a part in layers. This process is very close to the classic "3D printer" with plastic FDM.